# Writing byte[] array to text file in Android

Tags: android, arrays, fileoutputstream

So many examples for this question. I tried and still doesn't work. 
Test.txt file is created. But no data is written into the test.txt file.
What is wrong with my code? I have permission in the `Manifest` file as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Code:

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
        "/PrintFiles";
File file = new File(file_path+"/test.txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
   try {
    file.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] b = {65,66,67,68,69};
fos.write(b);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc  `openFileOutput` will

```
Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing. Creates the file if it doesn't already exist.
```

those files are under the.

```
data > data > your app id > files
```

but your file is not in internal folder its in external storage..

Change this line

```
fos = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

into

```
fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
```

And try..

Comment: +1 Perfect answer, I check OP's code in my pc, after your suggestion, It is writing well in file.

Answer (score 3):

Cause, you are creating file in **SDCard** but writing in **Internal Storage**. Try as follows...

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
        "/PrintFiles";
File file = new File(file_path+"/test.txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
   try {
    file.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] b = {65,66,67,68,69};
fos.write(b);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: Should be fos = new FileOutputStream(file);